# I'm trying to merge two extent reports using extent report json files..it's merged but screenshots are not reflecting

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, path, cucumber, extentreports

I'm using grasshopper library, according to the documentation provided, I have to pass two paths that where the json files located as well as media paths(screenshots).

```
List<String> jsonReports = Arrays.asList(new String[] { 
                "setup/first/ExtentJson.json",
                "setup/second/ExtentJson.json" });  

List<String> screenshots = Arrays.asList(new String[] { 
            "setup/first/media",
            "setup/second/media"});
```

and also final path where the merged reports will be placed.

```
String mergedReportsDir = "setup/final";
```

and trigger the merge using

```
pojoOption = PojoOptions.builder().jsonReportPaths(jsonReports).mergedReportDirPath(mergedReportsDir)
                    .configType("xml").mediaPaths(screenshots).build();

        Combiner.main(pojoOption);
```

Now the issue is, In the reports I can see it was merged, but screenshots are not coming. Ideally once I trigger the merge process, there should be merged json, one html reports and one media folder with screenshots placed in the `setup/final` folder, I can see json, html and media folder too but there isn't any screenshots in the `media` folder, so when I open the merged html reports, screenshots showing some broken thumbnail.

And also, I have checked the which path it's taking in the merged json, I found this

```
`"media":{"path":"../../screenshots/embedded1.png"}}`
```

this path was in the `extent.properties` file for individual run.

So, someone can help why screen are not reflecting in the merged json.

and `setup` is the directly under the project folder.

[this](https://ghchirp.site/2882/) is the link for the documentation I've used.